# Suggestion for a new flag

Tags: feature-request

As it stands, questions can only be flagged as duplicates if that same question has already been asked and answered. However, all too frequently an impatient user will ask the same question twice (or more), sometimes changing the wording only superficially, in order to attract more attention to their question.

Could there not be a flag for this? Something like 'Repetition'?

Answer (score 4):

It may seem harsh, but if some user posts one and the same question several times, it should be close-voted. That's it.

I mean, attracting attention is also done by editing and thus improving the original question, isn't it?

Comment: I agree, but unfortunately I don't get to close vote (and nor do you).

Comment: @vancoder Well, that is, of course, ... right. :) Maybe the 3k reputation needed for close votes should be thought over - especially when _low-rep users_ (at least below 3k) are meant to be of some assistance regarding that kind of questions/posts.

Answer (score 1):

I see no need for that. We take always the time to read up the context for a flag and decide case by case. You can use the custom message if you want.

I think there should rather be *less* prepared options. Some problems like *low quality* or *off topic* should be solved by the community (edit or close vote), not by moderators. The presence of these flags indicates the opposite.

Comment: It's often not possible to edit an off-topic question into an on-topic one. Also, as I understand it, a rep of 3000 is required to close vote.

Comment: Then … make some rep. 3000 is possible in two weeks. :) A realistic time is probably two months – not that long.

Comment: I'll get right on that. Feel free to donate by upvoting my question :)

Comment: "*3000 is possible in two weeks. :) A realistic time is probably two months – not that long.*". WPSE has **44** users with 3,000+ rep, out of about 265 users with 500+ rep (and almost 20K total users), in 41 months of existence. I don't think we've yet reached the "critical mass" that makes the prospect of earning 3,000+ rep *easy*.

Comment: ... and someone down-votes my question, in a facetious attempt at irony no doubt.

Comment: @ChipBennett Answer two or three questions each day, and you are there really fast. Most users don’t do that, but that doesn’t prove anything. But you are right: It is not easy.

Comment: @vancoder, downvotes in Meta [means disagreement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87475/185667) with the proposal. And it doesn't affect the rep anyway... Oh, yeah, I "disagreed" the Q too ;)

Comment: @brasofilo Got it, thanks.